# Inequality involving arithmetic means: $\prod_{\text{cyc: } a,b,c,d} \frac{a+b}{2} \le \prod_{\text{cyc: } a,b,c,d} \frac{a+b+c}{3}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a\geq b \geq c\geq d \geq 0$ (ordering matters). Prove that:
$$\dfrac{a+b}{2}\dfrac{b+c}{2}\dfrac{c+d}{2}\dfrac{d+a}{2}\leq \dfrac{a+b+c}{3}\dfrac{b+c+d}{3}\dfrac{c+d+a}{3}\dfrac{d+a+b}{3}$$

Note: if $a=b=c=d$, then the result is a direct consequence from property of arithmetic means.

Comment: The last fraction should be $\frac{d + a + {\boldsymbol{b}}}{3}$, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. $\frac{a_n+a_1+a_2}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Mongolian inequality and the key tool for proving it is
[Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata's_inequality).

Full proof (in russian) can be found [HERE, page 220](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/cb2b36c50ea59e4c7e11aa5d54f9c8af/mp198.pdf).

Comment: Since the google search for "Mongolian inequality" is heavily interfered with by social inequality in Mongolia, let me add a link to an English proof (complete, I think): http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h26103p163628

Answer (score 0):

The Khrabrov's proof see here:

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h75130p443216